# Dialog and auto-height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So for replies I created a a jQuery dialog. This dialog has the following settings:

```
$("#reply-window").dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  resizable: false,
  modal: true,
  autoResize: true
});
```

There is still a scrollbar inside of the dialog. If I change the CSS for #reply-window to

```
height: XYZpx;
```

I can modify the height attribute. With the default

```
height: auto;
```

The dialoge is too small and I have to deal with a scroll bar inside.

Comment: The simple suggestion.. overflow:hidden;  That will remove the scrollbar completely.

Comment: @Cam The dialog still has not the height it needs to display all the elements within than.

Comment: I'm not getting the same issue... anyway you could create a code snippet using StackOverflow's code editor?

https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: Having working code would be good.

Answer (score 1):

sorry for the answer, i still can not write comments.

are you using bootstrap? if yes, have a look on the modal and use this. it automatily is scrollable and you can put in whatever you want

Comment: I'm not using bootstrap and only use this for a small part of my site.

Comment: another way is to build your own modal, show a div witch z-index is higher than all other and position should be fixed, remove body's scroll function until you close your div (hide). dont forget to add a close button to your modal ;)

Answer (score 0):

you could set the min height attribute for the dialog box.

```
 minHeight: 600
```